# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $$\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}} dx$$

I got this integral while solving triple integral, but I cannot proceed now. I have tried substitution. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $x=a \sin^{2}(t)$. As $t $ varies from $0$ to $\pi /2$, $x$ varies from $0$ to $a$. The integral becomes $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\sin\, t} {\cos\, t} 2a sin\,t \cos \, t\, dt$. Now use the fact that $2\sin ^{2} t=1-\cos(2t)$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Thanks. it was easy but I guess I am having hard day today

Answer (score 2):

Try $x=a \sin^2 \theta$. The integral reduces to,

$$I = \int^a_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}\, dx = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{2\sin^2\theta \cos \theta}{\cos \theta}\, d\theta=\int^{\pi/2}_0 2\sin^2\theta \, d\theta = \int^{\pi/2}_{0}1-\cos2\theta \, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a-x=u^2$  then $-dx=2udu$  the integral changes to $\int _{\sqrt{a}}^0 \frac{\sqrt{a-u^2}}{u}(-2udu)$ now from here it's an integral of know form ie $\int \sqrt{(\sqrt{a})^2-u^2}$ I hope you can proceed from here.